# SQL - combine multiple columns into one for easy select and index

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, indexing

I have some table which must have some unique indexes includes multiple columns.

For example;

```
Date       |   ChannelId   |   SellerId   |   ProductId   |   TotalSale
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-08-08         1              1            1                100
2019-08-08         2              1            1                100
2019-08-08         3              1            1                100
2019-08-08         4              1            1                100
```

I have a unique index on `Date,ChannelId,SellerId,ProductId` columns.

Generally, I need to select one row by the unique index.

My proper query is

```
SELECT Date,ChannelId,SellerId,ProductId,Total 
FROM Reports
WHERE Date = @Date 
  AND ChannelId = @ChannelId 
  AND SellerId = @SellerId  
  AND ProductId = @ProductId
```

I know that the more condition in `WHERE` clause the slower performance.

I plan to add a varchar key column to the table for selecting single row easily. Like below.

```
Key                  |   Date       |   ChannelId   |   SellerId   |   ProductId   |   TotalSale
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-08-08_1_1_1       2019-08-08         1              1            1                100
2019-08-08_2_1_1       2019-08-08         2              1            1                100
2019-08-08_3_1_1       2019-08-08         3              1            1                100
2019-08-08_4_1_1       2019-08-08         4              1            1                100
```

By this way, I will have a chance to select a row by a single parameter.

```
 SELECT Date,ChannelId,SellerId,ProductId,Total 
 FROM Reports
 WHERE [Key]= @Key
```

However, I am not sure that this approach would be a good choice.

I know that `varchar` type performance would be slower.

I want to learn what are the pros and cons of both methods.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.  Someone with your reputation should know this.

Comment: You shouldn't have done that. Because I need answers both for SQL server and Postgresql.  I actually used both databases.

Comment: You should ask two questions then. What do you do if you get one answer for Postgres that doesn't work on SQL Server and one answer for SQL Server that doesn't work on Postgres? Which one do you accept?

Comment: "*I know that the more condition in WHERE clause the slower performance.*" that is a wrong assumption. Very often they improve performance as the database has to process fewer rows.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the more condition in WHERE clause the slower performance.

This is news to me.  If you have all the columns in an index and all the comparisons are equality, then the lookup should be fine.

There might be some microptimizations in terms of index usage -- comparing multiple columns incurs a very, very, very small bit of additional overhead.  But I would be surprised if you could consistently measure this on such a query.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. But, please think about a table which has millions of rows and thousands of concurrent transactions. Is it the same thing comparing one column or multiple columns in that case? If yes! Why are we need key,value DBs?

Comment: @MehmetOtkun . . . Yes it is the same, and it should be the same across databases with the right index.  Postgres has to do an additional check on the data page to see if the row is locked, but the index doesn't affect that.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun: I think that approach - if at all - might make things _slower_ because you increase the size of the table and you add _another_ index that must be maintained (as you need to keep the original unique index to ensure your business constraint). Plus: storing multiple different things into a single column is bad data modeling to begin with - what do you do with that key, if an UPDATE changes e.g. the value in the `channel_id` column?